# StackOverflow on querying embedded document

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Let me preface this by saying that I'm learning MongoDB still, so this could be a rather easy fix that my SQL brain cannot see.

For learning and researching purposes, I'm migrating an internal service for (Mexican) ZipCodes. This service uses MySQL as the database and has one field of the source data provided by the government as the main table, while many other fields were turned into secondary tables for repetitive data, such as `state`.

This approach is not necessarily the best for a NoSQL database (AFAIK since it relies heavily on `JOIN`s), so I rethought it and the zip code itself is the main attribute of my document, while other data is embedded in an array. My schema looks like this:

```json
'zipcode': {
    'code': String
    'state': String
    'settlements': [
        'settlement': String
        'municipality': String
        'city': String | null
    ]
}
```

All the data was imported after the schema was (strictly) defined, and everything but `city` is required.

I mapped this into a SpringBoot project like

```java
public class ZipCode {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String code;
    private String state;
    private List<Settlement> settlements;

}
public class Settlement {

    @Field("settlement")
    private String name;
    private String municipality;
    private String city;

}
```

and created a repository to search by zip code or municipality, which are the most important identifiers.

```java
public interface ZipCodesRepository extends MongoRepository<ZipCode, String> {

    @Query("{code: ?0}")
    ZipCode getByCode(String zc);

    @Query("{settlements.municipality: ?0}")
    List<ZipCode> getByMunicipality(String municipality);

}
```

I'm still just testing things out, so these two queries are enough. And yes, I've tried both queries directly through Compass.

The problem comes while trying the second query. It throws a `StackOverflowException` and while I can usually get what's wrong by reading it, this time is not a single trace. What I mean is that even if I get `StackOverflowException` every time I hit `getByMunicipality` the trace changes, although It seems to be a limited number of them.

At this point, I just don't understand what am I supposed to look for. The traces are the following (asterisks for emphasis by me):

Trace 1

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.base/java.util.Locale.isUnicodeExtensionKey(Locale.java:2283) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Locale.getUnicodeLocaleType(Locale.java:1354) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarDataUtility.findRegionOverride(CalendarDataUtility.java:136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:799) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:182) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.zero(Formatter.java:2450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.getZero(Formatter.java:4450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.localizedMagnitude(Formatter.java:4466) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3261) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2918) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143) ~[na:na]
        at org.bson.json.JsonParseException.<init>(JsonParseException.java:56) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        **at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]**
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.popToken(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:755) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:169) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
```

Trace 2

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.base/java.lang.CharacterData00.getType(CharacterData00.java:84) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Character.getType(Character.java:11031) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.lambda$findNonFormatChar$0(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:843) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$10$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringUTF16$CharsSpliterator.tryAdvance(StringUTF16.java:1231) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEachWithCancel(IntPipeline.java:163) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.findFirst(IntPipeline.java:552) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.findNonFormatChar(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:844) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:823) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:182) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.zero(Formatter.java:2450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.getZero(Formatter.java:4450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.localizedMagnitude(Formatter.java:4466) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3261) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2918) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143) ~[na:na]
        at org.bson.json.JsonParseException.<init>(JsonParseException.java:56) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        **at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]**
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.popToken(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:755) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:169) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
```

Trace 3

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarDataUtility.findRegionOverride(CalendarDataUtility.java:136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:799) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:182) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.zero(Formatter.java:2450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.getZero(Formatter.java:4450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.localizedMagnitude(Formatter.java:4466) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3261) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2918) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143) ~[na:na]
        at org.bson.json.JsonParseException.<init>(JsonParseException.java:56) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        **at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]**
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.popToken(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:755) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:169) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
```

Trace 4

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapSink(AbstractPipeline.java:547) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.findFirst(IntPipeline.java:552) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.findNonFormatChar(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:844) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:815) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:182) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.zero(Formatter.java:2450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.getZero(Formatter.java:4450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.localizedMagnitude(Formatter.java:4466) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3261) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2918) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143) ~[na:na]
        at org.bson.json.JsonParseException.<init>(JsonParseException.java:56) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        **at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]**
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.popToken(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:755) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:169) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
```

Trace 5

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:414) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:526) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.findFirst(IntPipeline.java:552) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.findNonFormatChar(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:844) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:815) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:182) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.zero(Formatter.java:2450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.getZero(Formatter.java:4450) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.localizedMagnitude(Formatter.java:4466) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3261) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2918) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143) ~[na:na]
        at org.bson.json.JsonParseException.<init>(JsonParseException.java:56) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        **at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]**
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.popToken(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:755) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:169) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
```

I see the common problem is on `JsonScanner.nextToken()`, but I have no idea how to handle that, or why this gets such an error. I also tried changing the return type to a simple `List<Object>` and even to `String` in case it was returning an array instead of a `Collection`, but those end up in the same exception. Furthermore, if this was a problem with the mapping to `List<ZipCode>`, then the `MongoRepository.findAll` method would've failed too, but it doesn't. So... I'm at loss.

Is there something wrong with what I have so far? Why can't I get the query `getByMinicipality` working? Any pointers will be appreciated!

My POM looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongoflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>mongoflow</name>
    <description>Demo project for migration to MongoDB</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and some sample data

```json
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b2"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Tzintzuntzan"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Yaguaro"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "El Pueblito"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "El Rincón"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58440"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b3"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Ihuatzio"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58442"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b4"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "El Jagüey"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Las Cuevas"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Los Corrales"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Nuevo Rodeo"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "San Isidro (Tziparamuco)"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "San Rafael"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Santa Cruz"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58443"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b5"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Coenembo"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "La Noria"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "El Tigre"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "El Pozo"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Fontezuelas"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58444"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b6"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Las Camelinas"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Los Granjenos (El Puerto de los Granjenos)"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Puerta de Coenembo"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Tzocurio"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Patambicho"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58445"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b7"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Colonia Lázaro Cárdenas"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Colonia San Juan"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "El Catorce"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Sanabria"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Tzintzuntzita"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Tziranga (Tzizanga)"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58446"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b8"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "El Tecolote"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Santiago Tzipijo"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "La Vinata"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "La Granada (El Mirador)"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Cucuchucho (San Pedro)"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58447"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64037f46ea9875dd382fa6b9"
  },
  "state": "Michoacán de Ocampo",
  "settlements": [
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Ichupio"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Isla de Pacanda (Isla Pacanda)"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Tarerío"
    },
    {
      "city": null,
      "municipality": "Tzintzuntzan",
      "settlement": "Ucasanastacua (El Espíritu)"
    }
  ],
  "code": "58448"
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field)

> To specify a query condition on fields in an embedded/nested document,
> use dot notation ("field.nestedField"). When querying using dot
> notation, the field and nested field must be inside quotation marks.

So, you need quotes for your field.

```
@Query("{'settlements.municipality': ?0}")
```

You can write this [without](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) `@Query` annotation also.

```
List<ZipCode> findBySettlementsMunicipality(String municipality);
```

or

```
List<ZipCode> findBySettlements_Municipality(String municipality);
```

Comment: Ok, that indeed works, but I have more doubts now. The most important one: Why the `StackOverflowException` is thrown? Which brings the second one: Why are quotes needed in this case? This is because, compared to JPA for SQL, dot notation implies a `JOIN` according to the mappings in `@Entity`, which is `@Document` in this case. So I just thought I could "lookup" as I did since `settlements` and `municipality` are fields in the mapped document... does this mean that, basically, every query in Spring Mongo is native by default?

Comment: Why the StackOverflowException? My guess is tries to figure out the field either from the method name or the query annoation and fails catastrophically.
Why are quotes needed? Because, mongoDB mandates it.